# NodeMcu (ESP8266) pinout problem

Tags: pinout, nodemcu

I am trying to use a nodeMcu in a project that involves:

- a microSD card reader (SPI),
- two devices that communicate with nodeMcu via software serial,
- a switch
- and 2 leds.

Currently the microSD is working ok, connected to nodeMcu pins D5, D6, D7, D8 (GPIO14, GPIO12, GPIO13, GPIO15). one of the software serials is using pins D1, D2 (GPIO5, GPIO4).
the switch is working at pin D0 (GPIO16), and the leds are at pins SD3 (GPIO10) and D3 (GPIO0).

But I still need to connect the other software serial (2 pins), and ideally I would left pin D6 (GPIO16) free, to be able to use sleep/wake function (right now I am using it to read the switch).

Is there any combination that would allow me to do what I want?
I have already tried some combinations (by trial and error) but I cant seem to find the correct connections (if there is any...).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the hardware serial port (GPIO 1 and 3) for the second serial port? I don't recommend using GPIO 10 as that is one of the pins that controls the external Flash chip. You could use GPIO 2, but it should not be low during boot.

Comment: @StarCat: I would like to leave hardware serial for debugging purposes...

Comment: Then you need to find other ways to use less pins to accomplish your goals. The ESP8266 unfortunately has a very limited amount of usable GPIOs.

Comment: @patsy2k You can certainly move the switch over onto one of the LED pins. That's low hanging fruit. But it buys just one pin. If one of the LEDs is always on, you could reduce two pins to one, freeing one more. But otherwise, you are stuck with two. You can always add something external to help out. But you may need to provide a complete discussion about what is used, when it is used, if all must be available and running at the same time or if there are ways to share pins (half-duplex, so to speak.) Right now, not enough info.